# Проблема с wi-fi в ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hp, wifi, ubuntu

На ноутбуке hp 630 установлена ubuntu 12.04 и такая проблема, что не работает ни блютуз, ни WiFi. WiFi адаптер atheros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проверь загружен ли модуль

```
# lsmod | grep ath9k
```

Если не загружен то

```
# modprobe -v ath9k
```

Comment: А если загружен? А если там не Atheros, а Realtek или Ralink?

Comment: не помогло :(`[sudo] password for pauk52: ath9k                 115995  0 mac80211              445648  1 ath9kath9k_common           13781  1 ath9kath9k_hw              375960  2 ath9k,ath9k_commonath                    19187  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hwcfg80211              178892  3 ath9k,mac80211,athcompat                 13105  5 ath9k,mac80211,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw,cfg80211`

Comment: Покажите вывод lspci и rfkill list

Comment: да ты прав не мешало бы и проверить )))

Comment: pauk52@pauk52-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list0: phy0: Wireless LANSoft blocked: yesHard blocked: yes1: hp-wifi: Wireless LANSoft blocked: yesHard blocked: no2: hp-bluetooth: BluetoothSoft blocked: yesHard blocked: no

Comment: pauk52@pauk52-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem (rev 03)01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по выводу rfkill, все заблочено. Соответственно как я уже и говорил

> rfkill unblock all должно помочь

Comment: никакой реакции